# Need help with creating sticker effect

Tags: animation, effects

I'm working on a 2D-ish animation (camera above looking straight down to flat objects) for an educational video and am wondering how to create two effects. The first one I'd need is the appearance of something being put on like a sticker. Where it starts out curved or rolled away from the camera and then it lays out flat.

Comment: Hi. This is two questions in one. Please [edit] your question to reduce it to one question. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need to as separate posts.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Please add some images to describe what you want, also